# javascript and IExplorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

```
  function getEntry(time)

    {
        var newdiv = document.createElement("div");
        if(time=='120')
        {
    var container = document.getElementById('require');

    newdiv.innerHTML = "<tr    id='a'><td><input type='radio' name='type' value='001' onchange='getRadioCheckedValue();' checked>Resume Writing<input type='hidden' name='service' id='1_59.95' value='Resume Writing'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><input type='hidden' name='price' value='59.95'>$59.95</td></tr>";


container.appendChild(newdiv);

}
```

i get nothing on the browser when i run this function...it works fine in firefox but noting happens on IE...no errors either.

can someone please explin how to fix this.

Thanks.

Comment: your newdiv is a div element and you wanted to insert table row in it.

IE is very strict about XHTML. you should create a table(with tbody optional) and append your row to it.

If this also not works then you can create all child elements like tr,td, and inputs, and can append it to table , tbody , tr and td.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to add `newdiv` to `body`:

```
document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
```

I also suspect id value like `1_59.95` with a point in between doesn't seem to be all right at least for the IE.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML you are injecting is bad formatted, meaning you have no closing tags on inputs /> (FF tries to help you and close the input tags however he sees fit) and a property with no value: "checked". IE translates checked to checked="checked".

As for the "adding" part I don't see an issue there as long as container actually is an HTML element.